# My QDateTime(QDate, QTime) constructor always creates "1 Januari 1970 00:00:00"

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, bug-reporting

[image: Debug info]

I'm having a weird problem with my QDateTime constructors, I'm creating a calendar program on Windows using Qt creator 3.1.1 and it's Based on Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32bit)

As you can see in the debugger info, `month = 9` and `year = 2014`

Still when the following code is executed

```
void GUICalendar::monthUpdated(int year, int month)
{
    QDateTime begin = QDateTime(QDate(year, month, 1), QTime(0,0,0));
    QDateTime end = QDateTime(QDate(year, month, begin.date().daysInMonth()), QTime(23,59,59));

    QList<AppointmentSolo*> soloList = m_calendar->AppointmentSoloBetween(begin, end);
    QList<AppointmentRepeat*> repeatList = m_calendar->AppointmentRepeatBetween(begin, end);
    QList<TodoBaseTask*> todoList = m_calendar->TodoTasksBetween(begin, end);

    m_dayView->update(soloList, repeatList, todoList);
}
```

this is what happens

```
begin = jan 1 00:00:00 1970
end = jan 1 00:00:00 1970
```

And I'm unsure why this happens, because my QDate in `begin` should be `sep 1 2014` still it's being changed into `jan 1 1970`

I'm already stuck on this problem for almost an hour, so I would be really grateful if someone here can explain what I'm doing wrong or why this is happening.

Comment: is it only in the debugger window? Do you get same output with `qDebug() << begin << end`?

Comment: Ah, no it gives `QDateTime("2014-09-01 00:00:00.000 Romance (zomertijd) Qt::LocalTime") QDateTime("2014-09-30 23:59:59.000 Romance (zomertijd) Qt::LocalTime")` So it seems it is actually working, I didn't knew you could do that, and I think this is going to help me A LOT! But is this intended that this happens in the debugger or is the debugger bugged?

Comment: qDebug() << "begin = " << begin.toString(); qDebug() << "end = " << end.toString(); gives me the expected result.

Comment: @Nazar554 if you want you can write that down as answer because it showed me how to proceed and thus actually solved my question.

Comment: Seems to happen only when you set the hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds to 0. Add even 1 ms and it should appear fine in the debug window. Not sure what that is all about.

Comment: Yeah it's really confusing, but i din't knew it would be right if you filled in every parameter.

Comment: @Thuga I was just thinking, it also happened with `end` (2014-09-30 23:59:59.000), so it does not ONLY happen when the hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds are 0.

Comment: @Dennis That date shows up fine on my end. Only if i change `QTime` to `0,0,0` it wont work. This is probably worth reporting.

Comment: @Thuga I'm only a first year computer science student, so do you mean to report it at the Qt bugreport forum? Or somewhere on StackOverflow?

Comment: [Qt bugreports](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/). [How to report bugs](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ReportingBugsInQt).